# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition (Incorrect Date format?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I've got the following error message within my ASP.Net application (C#):

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition
```

The table definition looks as following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoices] (
[Id]             INT        NOT NULL,
[EMail]          NCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[InvoiceNr]      INT        NOT NULL,
[Datum]          DATE       NOT NULL,
[AnzahlProdukte] INT        NOT NULL,
[Gesamtpreis]    MONEY      NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

My insert in C# looks like this:

```
string command = String.Format("INSERT into Invoices values ({0}, '{1}', {2}, '{3}', {4}, {5});", currId, EmailAdressCustomer, currInvoices, today, quantityCart, price);
```

The datatypes looks as following:

```
int currId = 0;
string EmailAdressCustomer = Session["CustomerEmail"].ToString();
int currInvoices = 0;
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
int quantityCart = 0;
double fullprice = Convert.ToDouble(Session["FullPrice"].ToString());
        SqlMoney price = new SqlMoney();
        price = (SqlMoney) fullprice;
```

I hope that anyone can help me. 
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the double value that string.Format transform in a string using the locale decimal separator. And if you have a locale where the decimal separator is a comma then you are ready for a big surprise.

For example, if you have

```
double price = 12.4;
string s = string.Format("{0}", price);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

in my locale (italian) the output is

```
12,4
```

as you can see, with string concatenation this becomes a new value that is not expected by the table definition

I could point to a different overload of string.Format like this one

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", price);
```

but this is just a way to cure the symptoms of the problem and not the real issue.
The only recommended solution to this problem is a parameterized query

```
 string cmdText = "INSERT into Invoices values (@id, @email, @inv, @dt, @qta, @prix)";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", currId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailAdressCustomer);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv", currInvoices);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", today);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qta", quantityCart);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pix", price);
 connection.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In this way, the proper handling of the decimal separator, string quotes, date formatting (and don't forget the whole Sql Injection vulnerability) is passed to the framework code that probably knows better how to do it.

Comment: How do I make a parameterized query?

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL, `Date` is not the same thing as `DateTime`. `Date` is a date only, `DateTime` has more data to hold time information as well. Switch it to a `DATETIME` in SQL. [Take a look here for more information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes)

**EDIT:**

You also need to defend against SQL injection. Do this with [parameterized SQL queries and commands](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter).

Comment: I've switched it to `DateTime` in SQL, still the same error. How do I have to build the SQL Query? It works like this in a few other queries without any problems.

Comment: See Steve's answer. The `Date` will truncate the time. The `double` is not correctly formatted.